# SELECt campo1 SQL y meter resultado en array PHP

Tags: php, pdo, select

Realizo esta consulta PDO para obtener todos los campos usuario y meterlos en un array, pero cuando accedo al array me sale "array".

El usuario es un correo electrónico y por tanto lleva @. Estoy probando en phpMyAdmin y me da problemas el @

```
 $nomPar = $bdd->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM datos WHERE id= :id AND usuario <> ':usuario'");
$nomPar->execute(['id' => $id],['usuario' => $usuario] );

$resultado = $nomPar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($resultado as $nombres)
{
    $nombres["usuario"];
}
```

Acceso:

```
$pdf->Cell(81,7,utf8_decode("  ".$nombres[$i]),1,0,'L','true');
```

He probado este código a sugerencia de @aeportugal:

```
$nomPar = $bdd->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM planes WHERE id= :id AND usuario != :usuario");
        $nomPar->execute([':id'=>$id, ':usuario'=>$usuario]);

    $nombres = $nomPar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

y sigue sin funcionar, en cambio si omito la clausula where de usuario si funciona.

```
$nomPar = $bdd->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM planes WHERE id= :id");
        $nomPar->execute(['id' => $id]);
    
        $nombres = $nomPar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

He llegado a la conclusión de que el problema está en que al tener @ debe ir entre comillas simples, y he porbado:

```
$nomPar = $bdd->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM planes WHERE id= :id AND usuario != ':usuario'");
    $nomPar->execute(['id' => $id,'usuario' => "'".$usuario."'"] );
```

pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Creo que la cuestión está en que en esta línea `$nomPar->execute(...)` estás metiendo varios array, es solo uno, mira bien la respuesta que puse.

Comment: Tengo puesto :  `$nomPar->execute([':id'=>$id, ':usuario'=>$usuario]);` es solo un array no?

Comment: habia puesto en la BBDD dato en vez de datos, esta bien tu solución, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar correctamente los datos a la consulta, debe ser ([leer documentación 1](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)):

```
$nomPar = $bdd->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM datos WHERE id= :id AND usuario <> :usuario");
$nomPar->execute([':id'=>$id, ':usuario'=>$usuario]);

$resultado = $nomPar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

En este punto `$resultado` ya es un array asociativo, no tienes que usar un `for` para capturar sus datos.

```
var_dump($resultado); // Imprime un array con los datos.
```

Si quieres un array unidimencional, solo con los valores de la columna `usuario`, [leer documentación 2](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
$resultado = $nomPar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Comment: Gracias @aeportugal … el campo usuario es un correo electrónico… cuando pruebo en PhpMyAdmin me da problemas el carácter @ … en tu código eso está solucionado?? Es que no sé si en PHP habrá que poner algún carácter como ‘ ‘ ( por ejemplo: ‘usuario’

Comment: he cambiado el código al tuyo y me funciona pero si la consulta es : `$nomPar = $bdd->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM planes WHERE id= :id");
$nomPar->execute(['id' => $id]);` el problema está en el valor de la variable usuario, que es un correo electrónico con @, que es el error que me está dando en PhpMyAdmin